¿Por qué no se añaden al proceso principal mis formularios en el panel de Windows Forms?
Depurando con un punto de control, me indica que la variable item sí obtiene los datos para comenzar con la iteración, pero al terminar no se ven los formularios en mi panel
private void crear_graficos()
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var datos = cNCredito.graficoUtilizado();
        foreach (var item in datos)
        {
            var grafico = new CreditoGrafica(item.credito, item.utilizado, item.nombre_tarjeta);
            grafico.TopLevel = false;

            if (item.nombre_tarjeta != "PRESTAMO")
            {
                this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    pnl_grafica.Controls.Add(grafico);
                    grafico.Show();
                }));
            }
        }
    });
}

